# How Complie SASS into Dreamweaver and SubLime Text Editor

Tags: css, sass

Compile SASS in to Dreamweaver and Sublime Text, i already search lot, but result i got it.

For Dreamweaver i edited Extension.xml and also MMDocumentTypes.XML but still no positive result found.

kindly help me out

Answer (score 0):

Please do follow the instructions for Sublime Editor

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SASS%20Build